# Why is the migration not being added?

Tags: asp.net

When trying to add a migration, I get the error "Unable to create an object of type 'AppDataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728%22)

DbContext code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ProductionAccountingData
{
    public class AppDataContext:DbContext
    {
        public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> options) :
            base(options) {
            try //noble crutch! (ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ*:･ﾟ✧
            {
                Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { };
        }
     
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();
        }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<Work> Works { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Code for adding context in the main project file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

string? connection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DepartmentDb");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDataContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connection));

var app = builder.Build();
```

Connection string from settings:

```
{
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Information",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "\*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DepartmentDb": "Server=localhost;Database=departmentdb;port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=122331"
}
}
```

I don’t understand what can cause an error. Can you tell me what the problem is?(I have two projects in my solution, one is responsible for the data, the other for my web application)

Comment: Can you include details of how you are attempting to create the migration? Are you using PackageManagerConsole in VS? What command are you using? etc.

Comment: I am using the Package Manager Console. 
"Add-Migration InitialDatabase"